# News site scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm developing `scrapy` project for scraping news from sites and saving them to Google Sheets. Source repository is [here](https://github.com/LotosikRa/climate-scraping).

I want to ask about my class that must be used as a parent for Scrapy spiders: what can be improved to make it the universal parent of spiders for any news-like web-sites? Also, I want to know how I can improve formatting and docstrings.

Code (v0.7.3):

```
class TemplateSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = None
    """ Spider name. """
    _start_path = None
    """ Relative path to page with news list. Used for `start_urls` field. 
    Minimal value = '/' """
    _start_domain = None
    """ First and only element of `allowed_domains` field. """
    _protocol = None
    """ 'http' or 'https' """

    _xpath_selector_list_tags = None
    _xpath_selector_list_text = None
    _xpath_selector_list_header = None
    """ These three `_xpath_selector_list_*` are used to find needed data by multiple selectors
    in different places. Must contain list of strings or tuple of strings."""
    _xpath_selector_path = None
    """ `_xpath_selector_path` is used to find relative href to article page when scraping from
    news list page. Must contain string."""
    _css_selector_news_list = None
    _css_selector_article = None
    """ These two `_css_selector_*` fields are used to locate news list div tag on news list page and
    to locate article div tag on article page. Must contain string."""

    ### "parse" methods
    def parse(self, response: scrapy.http.Response):
        self._scraped_indexes = self._scraped_in_past
        yield from self._yield_requests_from_response(response)

    def parse_article(self, response: scrapy.http.Response):
        # locate article
        article = self._find_article_in_responce(response)
        # produce item
        yield from self._yield_article_item(
            response,
            text=self._extract_text(article),
            header=self._extract_header(article),
            tags=self._extract_tags(article),
        )

    ### helpers
    def _clear_text_field(self, text: str) -> str:
        string = str(text).replace('\xa0', ' ')
        return string.replace('\n', '')

    def _convert_path_to_index(self, path: str) -> str:
        """ function that extracts unique part from given url."""
        raise NotImplementedError

    def _check_field_implementation(self, field_name: str):
        value = self.__getattribute__(field_name)
        if value is not None:
            return value
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError('Need to define "{}" field.'.format(field_name))

    @property
    def _scraped_in_past(self):
        return fetch_scraped_indexes(self.name)

    ### "yield" methods that returns generators
    def _yield_request(self, path_or_url: str):
        if '://' in path_or_url:
            url = path_or_url
            # extracting relative path from url
            _protocol = self._protocol + '://'
            path = path_or_url[path_or_url[len(_protocol):].find('/') + len(_protocol) + 1:]
        else:
            path = path_or_url
            url = '{protocol}://{host}/{path}'.format(protocol=self._protocol, host=self.allowed_domains[0], path=path)
        index = self._convert_path_to_index(path)
        if index not in self._scraped_indexes:
            yield scrapy.http.Request(url=url,
                                      callback=self.parse_article,
                                      meta={'index': index})

    def _yield_article_item(self, response: scrapy.http.Response, **kwargs):
        yield EventItem(
            url=response.url,
            index=response.meta['index'],
            **kwargs
        )

    def _yield_requests_from_response(self, response: scrapy.http.Response):
        """ Yields requests with `parse_article` callback.
        Takes response, finds, extracts news list, extracts from every path and generates requests."""
        for selector in response.css(self._css_selector_news_list):
            path = selector.xpath(self._xpath_selector_path).extract_first()
            yield from self._yield_request(path)

    ### "find" methods that returns Selectors
    def _find_by_xpath_list(self, article: scrapy.selector.SelectorList, xpath_string_selectors_list: list or tuple) -> scrapy.selector.SelectorList:
        selector_list = article.xpath(xpath_string_selectors_list[0])
        for string_selector in xpath_string_selectors_list[1:]:
            selector_list.extend(article.xpath(string_selector))
        return selector_list

    def _find_article_in_responce(self, response: scrapy.http.Response) -> scrapy.selector.SelectorList:
        return response.css(self._css_selector_article)

    def _find_news_list_in_responce(self, response: scrapy.http.Response) -> scrapy.selector.SelectorList:
        return response.css(self._css_selector_news_list)

    def _find_tags_in_article(self, article: scrapy.selector.SelectorList) -> scrapy.selector.SelectorList:
        return self._find_by_xpath_list(article, self._xpath_selector_list_tags)

    def _find_text_in_article(self, article: scrapy.selector.SelectorList) -> scrapy.selector.SelectorList:
        return self._find_by_xpath_list(article, self._xpath_selector_list_text)

    def _find_header_in_article(self, article: scrapy.selector.SelectorList) -> scrapy.selector.SelectorList:
        return self._find_by_xpath_list(article, self._xpath_selector_list_header)

    ### "extract" methods that returns strings
    def _extract_tags(self, article: scrapy.selector.SelectorList) -> str:
        return convert_list_to_string(self._find_tags_in_article(article).extract(), ',')

    def _extract_text(self, article: scrapy.selector.SelectorList) -> str:
        return convert_list_to_string(self._find_text_in_article(article).extract(), '', handler=self._clear_text_field)

    def _extract_header(self, article: scrapy.selector.SelectorList) -> str:
        return self._find_header_in_article(article).extract_first()

    @property
    def allowed_domains(self):
        return [self._check_field_implementation('_start_domain'), ]

    @property
    def start_urls(self):
        return ['{}://{}/{}'.format(self._check_field_implementation('_protocol'),
                                    self._check_field_implementation('_start_domain'),
                                    self._check_field_implementation('_start_path')), ]
```

About used but not declared functions:

- `convert_list_to_string` works similar to `join`, but calls `handler(item)` for every item in the list before adding it to output string
- `fetch_scraped_indexes` uses Scrapy Cloud API to fetch all finished jobs from last week and return a list of `index` field in every item.

About `index` - it part of the article URL that is unique for that article and can be extracted from any article URL on the web-site to indicate the page and not scrape it twice.

Working usage examples in the files in [this folder](https://github.com/LotosikRa/climate-scraping/tree/8d399c31b40b230ab679495ad78998ffe63b7839/scrapy_climate/spiders).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great job overall! I like how simple and readable the usage sample classes are.

Here are some of my high-level overview thoughts.

#### Code Organization

The class feels more like a *["God class"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)*, since it combines a lot of not directly related things - for instance, it has this `_clear_text_field` helper, different `_find*` and `_extract*` methods and `parse*` callbacks altogether in a single place. 
One way to approach the problem is to apply the ["Mixins" pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful).

#### Readability

You've provided quite a lot of comments, but some of the methods are not documented and it is not clear what is their purpose. Look at the `_find*` and `_extract*` methods - it is not easy to understand and keep track of what is going on there.

#### Code Quality

- you are using docstring convention of putting documentation into triple-quoted strings for comments. Instead, use a single `#` to denote a comment on a single line ([PEP-8 reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#block-comments)).
- also, *a comment precedes the line it is attached to*, not the other way around.
- you have a couple typos - you meant to call the methods `_find_article_in_response` and `_find_news_list_in_response` instead of `_find_article_in_responce` and `_find_news_list_in_responce`.
- since `SelectorList` is a subclass of a regular list, you should be able to use the "selector list comprehension" simplifying the `_find_by_xpath_list()` method:

  ```
  def _find_by_xpath_list(self, article: scrapy.selector.SelectorList, xpath_string_selectors_list: list or tuple) -> scrapy.selector.SelectorList:
      return scrapy.selector.SelectorList([article.xpath(string_selector) for string_selector in xpath_string_selectors_list])
  ```
- you can import `Request` directly from `scrapy`, replacing `yield scrapy.http.Request` with `yield scrapy.Request`.
- the `_yield_request()` method may use [`urlparse` module tools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! My triple-quote commenting style comes from using the `flask-admin` library where you can find a lot of them: [example of the class](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/model/base.py#L122)

Comment: How should I implement and use Mixins if some methods need documentation that depends on most of other methods? Have you some quick plan how should I organize methods in Mixins?

Comment: @IlliaAnanich at least, you can start with putting `_find*` and `_extract*` into a mixin and see how it looks - these methods feel like they should be grouped together. Thanks.

Comment: [That's](https://github.com/iAnanich/gismeteo-news-scraping/commit/45c5ecc39770ccbc74acdf37ef1517bde5b582ea) my first try to use Mixins here. Previous [commit](https://github.com/iAnanich/gismeteo-news-scraping/commit/cee2bc25f189d3f07f92af48abb3ae4f5ff6c7c5) contains all other changes from your answer.

Comment: @IlliaAnanich I think it looks cleaner than before. Please consider moving the mixing into a separate, say, `mixins.py` module. Thanks.

Comment: That's all the changes made because of your answer: [PR diff](https://github.com/iAnanich/gismeteo-news-scraping/pull/3/files)